# Disabling edittext from customerViewHolder is error

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a recycler view and it lists all names and their messages. (Messenger be like). Somehow the recycler view consists of name ,message and a small tag textview “customer closed” if they will going to click the recycler view that consist of tag “customer closed” they will not be able to send messages because its already closed. Otherwise all recycler view that consist of a tag “customer closed” it’s editext is set in to false.

```
public void bind(final Account account, final FirebaseChat chat) {
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = itemView.getContext();
            if (context instanceof NavigationActivity) {
                final Activity activity = (Activity) context;

                final Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), myChat.class);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_NEW, false);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_ACCOUNT, account);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_CHAT, chat);

                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    cName.setText(chat.getName());
    cName.setTypeface(chat.getReadCount() < chat.getNumMessages() ? Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD : Typeface.DEFAULT);
    cTextDate.setText(getFormattedDate(chat.getLastTime()));
    cTextMessage.setText(chat.getLastMessage());
    cTextMessage.setTypeface(chat.getReadCount() < chat.getNumMessages() ? Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD : Typeface.DEFAULT);



}




public void bind(final Account account, final FirebaseChatInfo customerInfo) {
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = itemView.getContext();
            if (context instanceof NavigationActivity) {
                final Activity activity = (Activity) context;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), myChat.class);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_NEW, false);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_ACCOUNT, account);
                intent.putExtra(ChatActivity.KEY_CHAT_INFO, customerInfo);

                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });




    cName.setText(chatInfo.getName());
    cName.setTypeface(chatInfo.isLastVisitorMessaged() ? Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD : Typeface.DEFAULT);
    cTextDate.setText(getFormattedDate(chatInfo.getLastTime()));
    cTextMessage.setText(chatInfo.getLastMessage());
    cMessage.setTypeface(chatInfo.isLastVisitorMessaged() ? Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD : Typeface.DEFAULT);

    this.shoptag = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shoptag);
    shoptag.setText(chatInfo.getShop_id());
    this.customerclosed = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customer_closed);
    this.customerclosed.setVisibility(chatInfo.isClosed() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    this.message_editext = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_editext);

    message_text.setEnabled(!chatInfo.isClosed());

    if(customerInfo.isClosed())
    {

        message_text.setEnabled(false);


    }else {

        message_textt.setEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

i got this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Means `message_text ` is `null` are you sure `EditText` with `R.id.message_editext` id is available in layout ?

Comment: `message_text` and the second one has `message_textt`. they are not in t code. if they are null then this will obvously come

Comment: message_text.setEnabled(false) , your edit_text declaration is something like this. this.message_editext = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_editext);
 , so probably your code should be, message_editext.setEnabled(true) or message_editext.setEnabled(false)

Comment: same error @HourGlass

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.message_editext = (EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_editext);

   message_text.setEnabled(!chatInfo.isClosed());

    if(customerInfo.isClosed())
    { 

        message_editext.setEnabled(false); 


    }else { 

        message_editext.setEnabled(true); 
    }
```